# Understanding use-case of Puppet in Windows deployment automation

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, powershell, puppet, docker

I have to automate few tasks in Windows environment. Technologies in use are MS SQL Server 2008, IIS, MSMQ etc. All dependencies for running the application are installed on a single machine. However, on production environment, dependencies are setup on different instances. Installation of dependencies (SQL server, IIS, etc) on any instance are all manual as of now.

First thing that i am planning to do is to create a base image which would contain all the dependent components (softwares). I think Puppet and Powershell along with Jenkins will help me in this. I am new to both Puppet and Powershell.

My goal is:
1) to automate installation of softwares on base machine.
2) use this image on all (or most) environments (Dev, Integration, Staging, UAT, Production)

Both the above steps should be automated.

Now the confusion that i have is if i use Powershell for say, installing SQL server (and other softwares too), then where does Puppet comes into picture? I can invoke this Powershell script from Jenkins to deploy on different environments by using custom config files for environments. Am i not understanding the real use-case of Puppet here? Should i be actually using any other tool such as Docker etc? Please guide me.

Comment: "Now the confusion that i have is if i use Powershell for say, installing SQL server (and other softwares too), then where does Puppet comes into picture? " -- you already appear to have decided to use Puppet earlier in the question. Except you're not sure if you should be using docker, though I'm willing to guess you're not sure how. FIRST TIP: Decide how to solve your problem then decide what tools will be a good fit for that solution; this will work so much better than just throwing every trendy devops tool du jour at the problem and hoping one of them sticks.

Comment: I have not really decided to use Puppet although the subject says so. Actually, the team that i have been assigned to seems to be evaluating Puppet for some time. However, i can still suggest if there's something better. The intent of the question was to hear suggestions from people who have already come across such scenario. I'm definitely open to suggestions as the work is to start almost from scratch. My only concern is that i should not be using a tool just because it's hot in the market. If it fits my requirement and helps ease my work, then i'm game for it.

Comment: My high-level approach to solve the problem is already mentioned in step 1 and 2. If there's a better alternative to it, i'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PowerShell vs Puppet is the wrong question

This isn't even really a thing. [Puppet can run PowerShell scripts](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/powershell). But there is another big reason the two are not really comparable.

PowerShell is procedural, Puppet is declarative. You can also use [PowerShell with Puppet](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/powershell), provided you use methods to make those calls to the scripts have an idempotence check.

```
exec { 'rename-guest':
  command   => file('guest/rename-guest.ps1'),
  onlyif    => file('guest/guest-exists.ps1'),
  provider  => powershell,
  logoutput => true,
}
```

Puppet also has reporting, diffing, automatic correction of changes outside of Puppet (known as configuration drift), and many more features that make it a configuration management tool and not a scripting language.

[Puppet + PowerShell](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/powershell) is a much more complete solution. Now let's perhaps look at using native resources to really reduce code.

#### Example - Ensure IIS and ASP.NET Installation

Let's say you want to run a script to ensure the installation of IIS and ASP.NET. You would need to ensure that you provide all of the proper checks so that if that script is run more than once, it would not error. You would basically want to ensure that IIS is installed and ASP.NET is configured and exit otherwise.

Doing this in Puppet is trivial. Say this is deploying to a Windows Server 2012 box:

```
  windowsfeature { 'Web-WebServer':
    installmanagementtools => true,
  } ->
  windowsfeature { 'Web-Asp-Net45':
  }
```

This is ***literally*** all you need to ensure IIS and ASP.NET is installed. Imagine the amount of lines of PowerShell you would need to write to do the same.

There is a more complete example of this for setting up a website complete with permissions at [puppet-chocolatey_server](https://github.com/chocolatey/puppet-chocolatey_server/blob/master/manifests/init.pp).

#### Managing SQL Server Install

You can use the [SQL Server module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/sqlserver). Here is an example (there are more involved examples available):

```
sqlserver_instance{ 'MSSQLSERVER':
  features              => ['SQL'],
  source                => 'E:/',
  sql_sysadmin_accounts => ['myuser'],
}
```

#### Installing Software

This becomes trivial when you use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

- Yes, Chocolatey builds on unattended installations and PowerShell.
- Yes, Chocolatey works with zips and runtime binaries.
- No, it does not require internet.
- Nor does it require you to download things at runtime from the internet.

Chocolatey is a complete software management tool that [integrates right into Puppet](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/chocolatey).

Organizations that typically use Chocolatey do not use the [community package repository](https://chocolatey.org/packages) (https://chocolatey.org/packages) because the packages offered there ***are*** subject to distribution rights and need to download from official locations at runtime. Organizations typically have a very low tolerance for breakages, so they create and host their own packages (internally they do not have the distribution legalities). In that way the process is completely secure, repeatable, and reliable.

```
package { 'notepadplusplus':
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => 'chocolatey',
  source   => 'https://internal/odata/repo/',
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! :) Just to clarify, i do know that comparing Powershell with Puppet isn't the right thing. I was just not sure whether using the two together will make sense in the overall picture. From your reply, it seems i can just use Puppet to accomplish my task.

Comment: By the way, i was hearing the term Desired State Configuration (DSC) for some time but never really checked. A day ago, read that it's Microsoft's approach to configuration management on similar lines as Puppet, Chef etc. However, from what i read, going with Puppet would be better for now. DSC is relatively new and Puppet is anyways providing support for several DSC resources.